# Plotting interaction effects in Bayesian models (using rstanarm)

Tags: r, bayesian, stan, rstan

I'm trying to show how the effect of one variables changes with the values of another variable in a Bayesian linear model in rstanarm(). I am able to fit the model and take draws from the posterior to look at the estimates for each parameter, but it's not clear how to give some sort of plot of the effects of one variable in the interaction as the other changes and the associated uncertainty (i.e. a marginal effects plot). Below is my attempt:

```
library(rstanarm)

# Set Seed
set.seed(1)

# Generate fake data
w1 <- rbeta(n = 50, shape1 = 2, shape2 = 1.5)
w2 <- rbeta(n = 50, shape1 = 3, shape2 = 2.5)

dat <- data.frame(y = log(w1 / (1-w1)),
                  x = log(w2 / (1-w2)),
                  z = seq(1:50))

# Fit linear regression without an intercept:
m1 <- rstanarm::stan_glm(y ~ 0 + x*z, 
                         data = dat,
                         family = gaussian(),
                         algorithm = "sampling",
                         chains = 4,
                         seed = 123,
                         )


# Create data sets with low values and high values of one of the predictors
dat_lowx <- dat
dat_lowx$x <- 0

dat_highx <- dat
dat_highx$x <- 5

out_low <- rstanarm::posterior_predict(object = m1,
                                   newdata = dat_lowx)

out_high <- rstanarm::posterior_predict(object = m1,
                                        newdata = dat_highx)

# Calculate differences in posterior predictions
mfx <- out_high - out_low

# Somehow get the coefficients for the other predictor?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this (linear, Gaussian, identity link, no intercept) case,

```
mu = beta_x * x + beta_z * z + beta_xz * x * z 
   = (beta_x + beta_xz * z) * x 
   = (beta_z + beta_xz * x) * z
```

So, to plot the marginal effect of `x` or `z`, you just need an appropriate range of each and the posterior distribution of the coefficients, which you can obtain via

```
post <- as.data.frame(m1)
```

Then

```
dmu_dx <- post[ , 1] + post[ , 3] %*% t(sort(dat$z))
dmu_dz <- post[ , 2] + post[ , 3] %*% t(sort(dat$x))
```

And you can then estimate a single marginal effect for each observation in your data by using something like the below, which calculated the effect of `x` on `mu` for each observation in your data and the effect of `z` on `mu` for each observation.

```
colnames(dmu_dx) <- round(sort(dat$x), digits = 1)
colnames(dmu_dz) <- dat$z
bayesplot::mcmc_intervals(dmu_dz)
bayesplot::mcmc_intervals(dmu_dx)
```

Note that the column names are simply the observations in this case.

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear to me what I'm seeing here. It looks like the assignment to dmu_dx is calculating a marginal effect for each draw from the posterior. That's fine, but it's an avg marginal effect.  If I want to specify though "the effect of increasing z from a to b on the effect of y" then jisn't the solution something more like dmu_dx1 <- post[ , 1] + post[ , 3] %*% t(rep(a, nrow(x)))   and dmu_dx2 <- post[ , 1] + post[ , 3] %*% t(rep(b,nrow(x)) then subtract the two: diff <- dmu_dx2 - dmu_dx2  ?

Also not clear what colnames(dmu_dx) <- round(sort(dat$x), digits = 1) is intended to do.

Comment: The assignment to `dmu_dx` (or `dmu_dz`) creates one marginal effect for each point in `dat`, and assigning the same thing to `colnames(dmu_dx)` puts that value on the vertical axis of `mcmc_intervals`. This is valid for the _marginal_ effect (instantaneous rate of change) of a truly continuous predictor. If you wanted the posterior distribution of a change in a dummy variable from 0 to 1 or more generally `a` and `b`, you could do along the lines that you suggest.

Comment: I followed this and it made a plot like this https://teblunthuis.cc/outgoing/Goodrich_Marginal_Effects_Plot.png

I have too much data. Should have graphed a sample.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use either the [ggeffects-package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=ggeffects), especially for marginal effects; or the [sjPlot-package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=sjPlot) for marginal effects and other plot types (for marginal effects, **sjPlot** simply wraps the functions from **ggeffects**).

To plot marginal effects of interactions, use `sjPlot::plot_model()` with `type = "int"`. Use `mdrt.values` to define which values to plot for continuous moderator variables, and use `ppd` to let prediction be based on either the posterior distribution of the linear predictor or draws from posterior predictive distribution.

```
library(sjPlot)
plot_model(m1, type = "int", terms = c("x", "z"), mdrt.values = "meansd")
```

[image]

```
plot_model(m1, type = "int", terms = c("x", "z"), mdrt.values = "meansd", ppd = TRUE)
```

[image]

or to plot marginal effects at other specific values, use `type = "pred"` and specify the values in the `terms`-argument:

```
plot_model(m1, type = "pred", terms = c("x", "z [10, 20, 30, 40]"))
# same as:
library(ggeffects)
dat <- ggpredict(m1, terms = c("x", "z [10, 20, 30, 40]"))
plot(dat)
```

[image]

There are more options, and also different ways of customizing the plot appearance. See related help files and package vignettes.